# Is there a way to handle form post data in a Web Api controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In `ASP.NET MVC` , one can access the form post data:

```
var thisData = Request.Form["this.data"];
```

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality in a `Web API`  [ApiController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API has become significantly more robust in dealing with different HTTP scenarios - especially streaming. As such only media type formatters normally touch the content and have to make a coherence of the content.

In ASP.NET MVC, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type is a first class citizen (and treated especially since this is the content type of 95% of the POST requests) and we have the `FormsCollection` to provide dictionary access in access, whenever it is defined as an input parameter.

In ASP.NET Web API, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is yet another content type, and supposed to be read by its MediaTypeFormatter. As such ASP.NET Web API cannot make any assumption about the `Forms`.

The normal approach in ASP.NET Web API is to represent the form as a model so the media type formatter deserializes it. Alternative is to define the actions's parameter as `NameValueCollection`:

```
public void Post(NameValueCollection formData)
{
   var value = formData["key"];
}
```

Comment: Suppose you had some values that were known, and some that are dynamic.  Is there a way to specify a model type for the known ones, AND get the rest in the collection.  Something like: `public void Post(PostData model, NameValueCollection formData)`?

Comment: Using NameValueCollection did not work for me, but it worked with FormDataCollection

Comment: NameValueCollection did not work for me too. I used FormDataCollection as @Pyfhon.

Answer (score 18):

Well, it is not possible because `HttpRequestMessage` doesn't provide that kind of collection out of the box.

However, if your application is hosted under ASP.NET, you can get to the current `HttpContext` object and get the form values from there:

```
public class CarsController : ApiController {

    public string[] Get() {

        var httpContext = (HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
        var foo = httpContext.Request.Form["Foo"];

        return new string[] { 
            "Car 1",
            "Car 2",
            "Car 3"
        };
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way of doing this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to Aliostad's method, one can do:

```
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    NameValueCollection formData = await request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have an `HttpRequestMessage`, you have a couple of options:

By referencing [`System.Net.Http.Formatting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/), you can use the [`ReadAsFormDataAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj125353(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method.

```
var formData = await message.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();
```

If you don't want to include that library, you can do the same thing manually by using the `HttpUtility` helper class in `System.Web`.

```
public async Task<NameValueCollection> ParseFormDataAsync(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    string formString = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var formData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(formString);
    return formData;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["key"];
```

Comment: HttpContext isn't available in WebApi apps.