# Does WebApi support application/x-www-form-urlencoded out of the box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am trying to setup an api to allow a 3rd parties webhooks a destination to post application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

I have only ever worked with json and xml with the webapi.

Do I need to create a custom mediatype to accept this or should it work by default?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE

I took a look at the example provided however I am still not to sure an example of the data the webhook will send to my api looks like.

How am I meant to setup my controller to accept this?

```
POST /some-path HTTP/1.1
Host: your.host.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 2837
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: /
```

environment=prod&domain_prefix=example&type=product.update&payload=%7B%22id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22retailer_id%22%3A%229a5521c3-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22sku%22%3A%229416050901074%22%2C%22handle%22%3A%221000001%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22USER%22%2C%22active%22%3A%221%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Ginger+Beer%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22%3Cp%3EA+delicious+ginger+beer+that+is+both+refreshing+and+good+value+for+money.%3C%5C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%22supplier%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%229fc84329-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22retailer_id%22%3A%229a5521c3-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Brewer+Supplies+Ltd.%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22We+supply+all+things+brewed%5Cn%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22USER%22%7D%2C%22brand%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%229fb8e69d-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Vaughan%27s+Ginger+Beer+Brewing+Company%22%7D%2C%22inventory%22%3A%5B%7B%22product_id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22outlet_id%22%3A%229aee412b-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22attributed_cost%22%3A%221%22%2C%22count%22%3A%2222%22%2C%22reorder_point%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22restock_level%22%3A%2240%22%7D%2C%7B%22product_id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22outlet_id%22%3A%229ae97219-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22attributed_cost%22%3A%221%22%2C%22count%22%3A%2214%22%2C%22reorder_point%22%3A%226%22%2C%22restock_level%22%3A%2220%22%7D%5D%2C%22price_book_entries%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%22a1098b59-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22product_id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22price%22%3A%222.00%22%2C%22tax%22%3A%220.25%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22BASE%22%2C%22customer_group_id%22%3A%229b097e69-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22customer_group_name%22%3A%22All+Customers%22%2C%22tax_id%22%3A%229a025ff0-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22tax_name%22%3A%22NZ+GST%22%2C%22tax_rate%22%3A%220.150000%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22a1318cf0-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22product_id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22price%22%3A%221.90%22%2C%22tax%22%3A%220.24%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22GENERAL%22%2C%22customer_group_id%22%3A%229b097e69-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22customer_group_name%22%3A%22All+Customers%22%2C%22tax_id%22%3A%229a025ff0-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22tax_name%22%3A%22NZ+GST%22%2C%22tax_rate%22%3A%220.150000%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22a13a6320-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22product_id%22%3A%229fe945bc-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22min_units%22%3A%2210.00%22%2C%22price%22%3A%221.50%22%2C%22tax%22%3A%220.19%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22BASE%22%2C%22customer_group_id%22%3A%229b097e69-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22customer_group_name%22%3A%22All+Customers%22%2C%22tax_id%22%3A%229a025ff0-2d20-11e2-8057-080027706aa2%22%2C%22tax_name%22%3A%22NZ+GST%22%2C%22tax_rate%22%3A%220.150000%22%7D%5D%7D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to handle form post data in a Web Api controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593595/is-there-a-way-to-handle-form-post-data-in-a-web-api-controller)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it supports it out of the box.

Please, take a look on that sample: [ASP.NET Web API: Sending Form-Url-Encoded Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1)

Comment: Redirected, basically dead, link

Comment: I fixed the link. Thank you for raising this.